# Matching similar words from two character vectors in R

Tags: r, string, match, character

I have the following case in R which I got some identifiers divided in these objects.

```
uniques_df_deps <- c("Antioquia",  "Atlántico",  "Bogotá",    "Bolívar",    "Boyacá", "Caldas",    "Caquetá",    "Cauca",  "Cesar", "Córdoba",    "Cundinamarca",  "Chocó", "Huila",  "La Guajira",  "Magdalena", "Meta", "Nariño", "Norte de Santander",     "Quindío",    "Risaralda",  "Santander", "Sucre",  "Tolima", "Valle del Cauca",        "Arauca", "Casanare",   "Putumayo",  "San Andrés y Providencia", "Amazonas",   "Guainía",   "Guaviare",   "Vaupés", "Vichada")

uniques_df_gini<- c("Antioquia", "Atlántico", "Bogotá D.C.", "Bolívar",   "Boyacá",   "Caldas",    "Caquetá",   "Cauca", "Cesar", "Chocó",    "Córdoba",   "Cundinamarca",  "Huila", "La Guajira",  "Magdalena",  "Meta",  "Nariño",    "Norte de Santander","Quindío",   "Risaralda",  "Santander", "Sucre", "Tolima",    "Valle del Cauca")
```

And my desired output is to show a table in which I can see the closest match from uniques_df_deps in uniques_df_gini.

Which will look something like this:

| uniques_df_deps | uniques_df_gini |
| --- | --- |
| Antioquia | Antioquia |
| Atlántico | Atlántico |
| Bogotá | Bogotá D.C. |
| ... | ... |
| Arauca | NA |
| Casanare | NA |

The task has become more difficult than expected and I looked packages as amatch() and others but without giving a clear structure like my desired output. And previous examples and answers are not giving me my desire output when I try it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may use `agrep`

```
matched <- sapply(uniques_df_deps, function(x){
  tmp <- agrep(x, uniques_df_gini, max = 2, ignore.case = TRUE, value=TRUE)  
  tmp <- ifelse(length(tmp)==0, NA, tmp)
})


data.frame(uniques_df_deps = uniques_df_deps,
           uniques_df_gini = matched,
           row.names = NULL)

          uniques_df_deps    uniques_df_gini
1                 Antioquia          Antioquia
2                 Atlántico          Atlántico
3                    Bogotá        Bogotá D.C.
4                   Bolívar            Bolívar
5                    Boyacá             Boyacá
6                    Caldas             Caldas
7                   Caquetá            Caquetá
8                     Cauca             Caldas
9                     Cesar              Cesar
10                  Córdoba            Córdoba
11             Cundinamarca       Cundinamarca
12                    Chocó              Chocó
13                    Huila          Antioquia
14               La Guajira         La Guajira
15                Magdalena          Magdalena
16                     Meta            Caquetá
17                   Nariño             Nariño
18       Norte de Santander Norte de Santander
19                  Quindío            Quindío
20                Risaralda          Risaralda
21                Santander Norte de Santander
22                    Sucre              Sucre
23                   Tolima             Tolima
24          Valle del Cauca    Valle del Cauca
25                   Arauca              Cauca
26                 Casanare               <NA>
27                 Putumayo               <NA>
28 San Andrés y Providencia               <NA>
29                 Amazonas               <NA>
30                  Guainía               <NA>
31                 Guaviare               <NA>
32                   Vaupés               <NA>
33                  Vichada               <NA>
```